# Passing ref as props to get offsetTop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ref, use-ref

I have one component which I want to get ref and pass it to other component (fixed to top navbar with opacity 0) to check when the offsetTop of this ref is smaller than window.pageYOffset and if it is, change my state and set opacity of my navbar to 1. The problem is when I pass the ref, the other components gets null causing errors. How do I pass this ref when it's not null?

```
const galleryRef = useRef(null);

 <div className="gallery py-5 border" ref={galleryRef}>
      <FixedNavbar ref={galleryRef} />
</div>
```

FixedNavBar.js

```
const handleFixedNavbar = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > ref.current.offsetTop) {
      setIsFixed(true);
    } else {
      setIsFixed(false);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleFixedNavbar);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleFixedNavbar);
    };
  }, []);

<div ref={navMenusRef} className={`${isFixed ? 'fixed-nav' : ''}`}>
      {navMenus.map((item, index) => (
        <Link
          key={index}
          to={item.type}
          data-id={item.id}
        >
          {item.name}
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Callback Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) with `useState()` to cause a re-render when the ref is updated:

```
const [galleryRef, setGalleryRef] = useState(null);

 <div className="gallery py-5 border" ref={setGalleryRef}>
      <FixedNavbar galleryRef={galleryRef} />
</div>
```

The ref is passed as a standard prop (`galleryRef`), and the `useEffect()` is dependent on it, and would be called whenever it changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!galleryRef) return; // do nothing when ref is not set
  
  const handleFixedNavbar = () => {
    setIsFixed(window.pageYOffset > galleryRef.offsetTop); // sets true or false according to condition
  };

  handleFixedNavbar(); initial set

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleFixedNavbar);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleFixedNavbar);
  };
}, [galleryRef]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( I think the problem is that the props is passed when ref isn't created yet and current is always null, Is there a way to pass ref only when ref is already created?

Comment: See Ori's conditional rendering if ref is null